# snakemake yaml configuation for paired bwa align

Tags: snakemake

I would like to create a simple  snakemake file for bwa align some data. I have problems n  wildcard and input used

config.yml

```
samples:
    432:
      - "432_L001"
      - "432_L002"
units:

  432_L001:
         - "/illumina/RAW/432_CGATGT_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz"
         - "/illumina/RAW/432_CGATGT_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz"
```

this is  the snakemake file and bwa rules

```
from snakemake.exceptions import MissingInputException

rule bwa_mem:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: config["units"][wildcards.unit]
    output:
        temp("mapped_reads/sam/{unit}.sam")
    params:
        sample=lambda wildcards: UNIT_TO_SAMPLE[wildcards.unit]
        #sample=lambda wildcards: units[wildcards.unit],
        #genome= config["reference"][genome_fasta]
    log:
        "mapped_reads/log/{unit}_bwa_mem.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/bwa/mem/{unit}.txt"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        '/illumina/software/PROG2/bwa-0.7.15/bwa mem {params.custom} '

        '-t {threads} {params.genome} {input} 2> {log} > {output}'

snakemake --configfile config.yaml  mapped_reads/sam/{unit}.sam
InputFunctionException in line 50 of /illumina/runs/FASTQ/pippo4/rules/bwa_mem.rules:
KeyError: '{unit}'
Wildcards:
unit={unit}
```

How can use wildcard for this analisys? Or what is the best way to  manage that  configuration files?

Comment: Is the above the complete snakefile? You need a way to generate the list of possible values for the wildcards. I suggest you read the config outside the rules and get the liste of values for the `unit` wildcards from there, then make an `all` top rule having as input the output of your mapping rule, `expand`ed on the list of possible values for `unit`.

Comment: It was resolved using  " on the name of th key of the units dictionary

Comment: @bli  sorry this is the complete script https://pastebin.com/3E8uKBLe